# If a steady state is not Lyapunov stable, does its basin of attraction have Lebesgue measure zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

Consider the $n$-dimensional [autonomous system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)) $\frac{d}{dt}\boldsymbol{y}(t)=f(\boldsymbol{y}(t))$ defined on $[a,b]^n$, where $\mbox{-}\infty<a<b<\infty$.$^1$

Suppose that $\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}$ is a steady state (i.e. $f(\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}})=0)$ but is *not* [Lyapunov stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability).$^2$ Does it then follow that its basin of attraction

$$\{\boldsymbol{y}(0)\in[a,b]^n: \lim_{t\to\infty} \boldsymbol{y}(t)= \tilde{\boldsymbol{y}} \}$$
has Lebesgue measure zero?

---

**Footnotes:**

$\quad $ 1. By this I mean that $f:[a,b]^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined in a way such that $\{\boldsymbol{y}(t):t\geq 0\}\subseteq [a,b]^n$ whenever $\boldsymbol{y}(0)\in[a,b]^n$. (And initial conditions not in $[a,b]^n$ are excluded from analysis).

$\quad 2.$ In the present context, $\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}$ is Lyapunov stable if $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$ s.t. if $\boldsymbol{y}(0)\in[a,b]^n$ and $||\boldsymbol{y}(0)-\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}||_2<\delta$, then $||\boldsymbol{y}(t)-\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}||_2<\varepsilon$ $\forall t\geq 0$, where $|| \cdot ||_2$ denotes the [Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm).

Comment: Footnote 1 means that $[a,b]^n$ is a positively invariant set of the system. Is that exactly what you meant?

Comment: @AVK Yes, exactly! That is a very useful term to know, thank you!